# FCM not working in targetting S+. Pending intent issue

Tags: android, fc

Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.

Comment: found a solution?

Comment: You need to check all your PendingIntents and all PendingIntents created by libraries you're using in the project. 
But even after this I'm still getting crashes from Samsungs on Android 12, but Pixel devices works fine

Comment: We need to add Pending intent with FLAG_MUTABLE for notification and also we need to update Firebase SDK to the latest version .